# XCode: How to change the embeded UIView of a container from a slider or a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiview

I am currently working on a iPhone app, I have a view controller with a container on the bottom half that has a different view controller embedded in it. Suppose I wanted to change the embedded view controller in the container to a different view controller with a slider or a button. How can I do this?

-Thank you for the time.

Comment: In your title you ask for replacing a UIView, yet in your boy of text you are asking for a view controller ... These are very different, so, which is it? What are you trying to accomplish, perhaps that might clarify your needs

Comment: I am trying to change a viewcontroler. My apologies, UIViewContainers contain UIView's and I am trying to change the UIView inside the Container